# Select only Unique customers with pure category_ SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select customers who have experienced only dine in and have never ordered online..I want to exclude customers who have experienced both dine in and ordered online

> ```
> customer   type   
> 1          Dine-in 
> 2          Delivery
> 3          Dine-in
> 4          Delivery
> 1          Dine-in
> 2          Dine-in
> ```

I want a query wherein the customer with id 3 gets selected since they haven't ordered online

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS A
WHERE type = 'Dine-in'
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM table AS B
        WHERE B.customer = A.customer
        AND B.type = 'Delivery')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want *customers*, I would suggest using aggregation:

```
select customer
from t
group by customer
having sum( type = 'Delivery' ) = 0;
```

Use `not exists` if you want the original rows.  However, your question suggests that you just want the list of customers.